# delete a part from the request.rawurl on a button server side click

Tags: c#

How can i remove a part from the request url inside a button server side click here is my code:

```
URL:http://localhost:51854/SupportWebsite/Dashboard.aspx?FromForum=T

NewURL:http://localhost:51854/SupportWebsite/Dashboard.aspx
```

I know that i can use the string properties like remove and replace but i don't want to use Responce.Redirect(NewUrl) at the end of my button click because it would make no sense why because the button do post back in his default functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Uri.GetLeftPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart.aspx) method:

```
string oldUrl = "http://localhost:51854/SupportWebsite/Dashboard.aspx?FromForum=T";
Uri uri = new Uri(oldUrl);
string newUrl = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
```